# Htaccess file override with fallback to original

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I am trying to understand what an overriding system looks like in apache htaccess. Is it possible to override files in `webroot/foo/` with those in `webroot/foo/override` recursively? For example in a request for `webroot/foo/sub/sub3/file.txt` i would like to return `webroot/foo/override/sub/sub3/file.txt` if it exists, or fall back to the original file `webroot/foo/sub/sub3/file.txt` and ultimately to a 404 error if it's a miss.

Also, is htaccess the best place to do such thing?

Comment: indeed it's a bit borderline... my position is that htaccess is a domain-specific language that has some programming features that allow to write simple algorithms and as such it is similar to a scripting language. e.g. regex is a form of micro-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` here like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /foo/(.*)\sHTTP.*$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/foo/override/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /foo/override/$1 [L,R]
```

These rules will capture a part of request after `/foo` then check if it the request is valid by adding `/override` otherwise , be as is so, either being correct request or handled as wrong request but, you should add rule to handle a wrong request if not existed in your original rules.

**Note:** change `R` to `R=301` if the rules above are ok